# Lombok EqualsAndHashCode with inheritance

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, lombok

I want to use lombok:EqualsAndHashCode considering only Id, setted on Item class, on top of a hierarchical strucure. These are my classes:
1.Process:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class Process extends ResourceWithFlows {

  @OneToOne
  private Cost cost;
  private UUID referenceProduct; //flowBaseId
  private UUID processBaseId;
  private UUID processTemplateId;
  private boolean paretoApplied;

  //ref
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_equipment")
  private Equipment equipment;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_production_line")
  private ProductionLine productionLine;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_company")
  private Company company;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_supply_chain")
  private SupplyChain supplyChain;

}
```

2.ResourceWithFlows:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class ResourceWithFlows extends Resource {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_flow")
    private Set<Flow> flows;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_elementary_flow")
    private Set<ElementaryFlow> elementaryFlows;
    
}
```

3.Item:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    @Lob
    private String description;
    @OneToOne
    private AuthUser creatorUser;

    @PrePersist
    void creationDate () {
        this.creationDate = LocalDateTime.now();;
    }

}
```

Is it correct or is there another way to compare by Id the children of item like Process?
I used callSuper=true and onlyExplicitlyIncluded=true in the children, setting @EqualsAndHashCode.Include on id attribute of the parent Item, but I'm not sure It's correct.

Comment: Is `Item` a superclass of `ResourceWithFlows` ? What's the relationship of `Item` with `Resource` ?

Comment: yes sorry, also Resource extends Item

Answer (score 1):

What you did does work, but seems completely unnecessary given your requirement. If you're only going to identify objects using the `id` field in the topmost class, there is no need to apply `@EqualsAndHashCode` everywhere down the hierarchy. The methods generated in `Item` will work for all subclasses.